# Want to get married but I am poor?

Tags: nikah

I am a male who is long term unemployed, I have tried to get cleaning jobs here in the UK where I live but to no success. To top it up I am not even qualified for welfare so what should I do to get married?

Comment: What is your school of thought? Sunni? Shia?

Comment: Sunni school of thought

Comment: You will need to fast.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get married you should first of all stand on your own feet.

As Allah said [4:34](http://legacy.quran.com/4/34):

> Men **are in charge of women** by [right of] what Allah has given one over the other and **what they spend [for maintenance] from their wealth**...

Scholars of the maliki and shafi'i school consider a faskh (invalidation of a marriage) as legal if the husband can't stay in charge for his wife and family.

So try to find a job, find work go and work earn your own money don't stay dependent on anybody, neither a government nor parents not anybody!
Don't forget that:

> "**The upper hand is better than the lower hand.** The upper hand is that of the giver and the lower (hand) is that of the beggar." (Sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/24/32))

Read also [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/9/86) which shows how important it is to work and have your own money instead of asking people help or receiving sadaqah or any kind of money. See also [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/34/25) and many others ...

If you then still consider marrying and can't afford marriage the option given by [Quran](http://legacy.quran.com/4/25) is not allowed or not possible these days as we don't have slaves and Islam doesn't really support slavery (but accept it). As you can't marry a chaste slave now (as they don't legally exist).

therefore as ozbek suggested until you can afford the conditions for marriage you should fast (as stated in ahadith like [this one](http://sunnah.com/muslim/16/3)) and work and earn your own money!

Also read [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/10680) on rights of spouses in Islam.

Comment: Why can a man not stay single this entire life? Is he of lesser value to Allah than someone who is married. Will Allah judge more severe than a man who is married. I don't think so!

Comment: @Yahya777 I didn't say anything about that. I only answered OP's question and he wants to get married. So don't make wrong assumptions please!

Comment: @Yahya777 Staying single is not forbidden in Islam but is not recommended as it is against nature. One can get on the wrong path.

Comment: A married man/ woman can t get on the wrong path?